# spring-data-mongo aggregation supports $getField

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to use $getField included in $project operation by spring-data-mongo, but I don't find any class or method for $getField. So I want to know how use $getField in spring-data-mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via `AggregationExpression` it is possible to add any operator that is not yet (see: [#4072](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/4072)) supported.

```java
project().and((ctx) -> new Document("$getField", "price.usd")).as("value")
```